# excel--various substrings in a cell and return different values

Tags: excel

I have a cell that has some or all of the following letters--T,A,B,C,F.  If it is an individual letter, I would want .105 returned for T or F; .263 returned if either A, B or C.  If multiple letters are found, I would want the sum of the letters found to be returned.--the example would be T,B in a cell should return .368 while A, B, C would return .79

I would like the value to be put in a single cell

Comment: Hello, can you share what you have tried?

Comment: What approaches have you tried so far?

Comment: Thanks to all who provided the ideas.  I have never worked with an array and I really didn't understand some of the commands/logic below.  Am sure they would work--I went ahead and used the non-array approach.  Best regards--

Answer (score 0):

[image]

It's an array formula so have to be entered while holding Ctrl-Shift `=SUMPRODUCT(((Table1[Letter])=TRANSPOSE(MID(D2,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(D2))),1)))*Table1[Value])`

Answer (score 0):

Another variant handling `,` in your criteria cell :

`{=SUM(IF(A2:A6=TRANSPOSE(INDEX(MID(SUBSTITUTE(F4,",",""),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(SUBSTITUTE(F4,",","")))),1),)),B2:B6,0))}`

[image]

Answer (score -1):

hate to use array so here is a non-array formula

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH("*T*",$A$2,0)),0,0.105)+IF(ISERROR(MATCH("*F*",$A$2,0)),0,0.105)+IF(ISERROR(MATCH("*A*",$A$2,0)),0,0.263)+IF(ISERROR(MATCH("*B*",$A$2,0)),0,0.263)+IF(ISERROR(MATCH("*C*",$A$2,0)),0,0.263)
```

Comment: Nested `IF`s are never the answer, even if the question asks for nested `IF`s.  It's a horrible practice that makes for unreadable formulas.